# Shortening mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a shorter way of writing this mysql query?

```
SELECT Ren, 
       CASE when Ron like '0_.' then '' else Ron end as Ron,
       CASE when Ron like '1_.' then '' else Ron end as Ron,
       CASE when Ron like '2_.' then '' else Ron end as Ron
FROM tbron
```

what I try to do here is when there is any of these values above, then it should result in ' ' empty.

Thanks!

Comment: first format your query properly i really dont understand what it is.

Comment: thanks. It's done by the moderator, I didn't know how to format it like that.

Comment: this will get you four columns of output, 3 of which are aliased as "Ron"...is that what you want? Or you want one "Ron" column?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Are you just trying to see if the value of Ron is exactly the same as `0_.`, `1_.` or `2_.`? If so, you could use `IN` instead of `LIKE` and combine the three columns back to one

Comment: There are 2 columns (Ren, Ron). I need just the  values of Ron to be empty if one of the above values are present.

Comment: may be you can do it using trenary operator with query.

Comment: Ok. I just asked because at present you have 4 columns in your query. If that's what you want then Dr Strange's answer below should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, for your help and interest. All good answers. Since I asked for shorter, I'll go with the shortest working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    Ren,
    IF ( `Ron` REGEXP '[0-2]\_\.', '' , `Ron`) AS Ron
FROM tbron
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. Underscore is a single character wildcard when used with LIKE but you are matching against the underscore character itself.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson - ups, my mistake

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT Ren, 
CASE
    WHEN Ron like '0_.' then ''
    WHEN Ron like '1_.' then ''
    WHEN Ron like '2_.' then ''
    ELSE Ron
END
FROM tbron
```

Answer (score 2):

I think below query should also work for you.

```
SELECT Ren, 
CASE
    WHEN Ron like '0_.' OR Ron like '1_.' OR Ron like '2_.' then ''
    ELSE Ron
END
FROM tbron
```

Comment: You're missing an OR otherwise this looks like a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you returning three columns with the name `Ron`?  That seems awkward.

Assuming that you really want just one column in the result set, combining the three conditions, the correct equivalent expression using regular expressions is:

```
SELECT Ren, 
       (CASE WHEN Ron REGEX '^[0-2].?[.]$' THEN '' ELSE Ron END) as Ron
FROM tbron;
```

Notes:

- `LIKE` patterns match the entire string; regular expression patterns match any substring.  To get the same effect with a regular expression you need to anchor the regular expression to the beginning and end.
- The `_` is a special character in a like patter that matches any character once.  The equivalent in a regular expression is `.?`.
- `.` is a special character in regular expressions so it needs to be escaped (which I usually do by making it a character class).

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I wanted to apply the CASE clause to the same column (Ron) in the wrong way. I realized my mistake after seeing the answers here.